# Wordpress: add custom page attribute

Tags: wordpress, templates, field, custom-attributes

I have the NextGEN Gallery plugin on my wordpress site. Normally I would add this short code in my page content to display gallery items:
[ nggallery id=5 template=custom ]

Now I'd like to replace this by adding custom fields in the Page Attributes setting when you are adding/editing a page. The custom fields would be "Gallery ID" and "Template name".

I'm of course using a custom page template. How can I retrieve the page attributes into this page template?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you say that? Don't they return anything? Did you placed the get_post_meta calls inside the Loop?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what Stratboy said. Documentation [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta). This is the setup that should work for you:

```
<?php    
    $gallery_ID = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Gallery ID', true); 
    $template_name = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Template Name', true);

    if ($gallery_ID && $template_name){
        //echo '$gallery_ID: '.$gallery_ID.'; $template_name: '.$template_name.';';
        echo do_shortcode('[nggallery id="'.$gallery_ID.'" template="'.$template_name.'"]');
    }
?>
```

Comment: I just edited this so the shortcode is output with quotes around the values, like so: 
[nggallery id="5" template="custom"]

Comment: I tried to use the plugin Simple Field to be able to add meta key/value to my page, but It seems that gallery_ID and template_name are empty. How should add the post meta to each page correctly?

Comment: In your question the custom fields you used were 'Gallery ID' and 'Template Name', so that's what the code above is looking for. If you named your field 'gallery_ID' instead then update the above snippet.

Answer (score 0):

So, first:

- have you already implemented the custom page template?
- have you already implemented the custom fields?

Anyway, generally, in a template you get your custom fields values using the get_post_meta function in the Loop, like this:

//the last param tell if you want the value returned as a string (true) or an array (false)
get_post_meta($post->ID,'field name',true);

You can echo the returned value or use it for other tasks.

Let me know.

Comment: Okey, nice, thanks! But how can I add a custom field option in the "Add Page" interface?